# Piping not working as expected npm scripts

Tags: css, node.js, npm-scripts

I am trying to get my sass file compressed using cssnano by passing the transpiled css as first argument to cssnano . It is not working as it creates a blank file only . The first script runs correctly and creates compressed css file. Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "cssnano",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build:css": "cssnano < main.css > main.min.css",
    "build:css1": "node-sass main.scss > main.css | cssnano > main.min.css"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cssmin": "^0.4.3",
    "cssnano-cli": "^1.0.5",
    "node-sass": "^3.13.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need main.css and main.min.css you can try this (as writing to a file obviously does not also add the content to the pipe):

```
node-sass main.scss > main.css && cat main.css | cssnano > main.min.css
```

Otherwise use this:

```
node-sass main.scss | cssnano > main.min.css
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Unix [`tee`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)) command, or the node equivalent, https://github.com/stefanmaric/ntee.

```
node-sass main.scss | tee main.css | cssnano main.min.css
```

If your script only has to work on Unix, use `tee`. If it has to work on windows, you will need to use `ntee`.